# How to remove characters from a string and save it in a list? - python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this string:

```
Frage\tf, -n 1. въпрос; питане; 2. проблем; eine dumme, peinliche ~ глупав, неудобен въпрос; jmdm. eine ~ stellen задавам въпрос (някому);
```

and I want to get just the beginning of it - till the first ";", remove the \t and the number with a comma(1.), and after that save it in a new list. It seems like an easy problem but I got stuck on it, so can someone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried a split method. Save the main string in a list, and remove the \t, but its a total mess. Should I use the split method for every single character that I want to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I've tried:

```
import re

text = r"Frage\tf, -n 1. въпрос; питане; 2. проблем; eine dumme, peinliche ~ глупав, неудобен въпрос; jmdm. eine ~ stellen задавам въпрос (някому);"
pattern = "^(.*?);"

x = re.search(pattern, text)
print(re.sub(r"\d.", "", x.group(1).replace(r"\t", "")))
```

Comment: In general, it works, but sometimes,  when the source is different (text)I get an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. Why its that so? Can you explain what are you doing with that code?

Comment: @EvrimYuzeir `re.search` tries to match a pattern, if nothing is found it will return `None`. If you try to call `.group()` on a `NoneType` object it will throw `AttributeError`. I just used your example, if you want to include more variations of your source text, you should then include some `if` statements etc to check if the value is `None`.

Comment: What should be the pattern if I want to check till  ";" or "." - pattern = "^(.*?);|\."  ?

Comment: @EvrimYuzeir Put that second part in a group. So `^(.*?)(;|\.)`. If you are not sure, a good way to check is to use [regex101](https://regex101.com/). There you can see the meaning and functions of regex characters and it's also a great tool to test regex in general.